# Blank pages after moving from Local development to Production

Tags: deployment

I'm very new to Craft and recently built my first Craft-powered website (locally) and it works fantastic. Now, I want to move it to production, and I'm having trouble. Locally, everything went very smooth with Composer but unfortunately, I can't do that on my hosting.

I went through the following steps:

1. Made a database backup through the Craft admin
2. Made a new database my website and imported it
3. Moved all files from local to production
4. Changed `.env` with the correct credentials and info

But after this, I only get blank pages (both index and admin)

What am i missing? Is there a better way (without using Composer) to deploy?

Comment: Have you checked that your public web root is correctly set in your hosting control panel? If you've uploaded everything in your working directory to the web root, the site may be accessible at mydomain.com/web.

Comment: If you could clarify "all files," we might be able to track down the issue—you've included the `vendor` folder and `.htaccess`?

Comment: I've uploaded literally all the files including vendor and the .htacces in the /web folder. When I go to the domain.com/web everything is also blank.

Comment: Another thing to notice is that I can't edit the domainroot with Apache since my hosting provider doest allow it. So I guess I have to do that with .htacces (tips for this?). I'm probably making a huge rookie mistake so already a big thanks to you guys for helping me. I'm so desperate to make this work.

Comment: I think i am one step closer now (i moved all the files to the root of the domain and changed /web to /public_html because i read that thats the right way to install craft on shared hostings. But i still get blanks

Comment: Have you verified your hosting environment meets the baseline Craft requirements? The next step I'd take is uploading a basic `index.html` or `info.php` (with just `<?php phpinfo() ?>`) to your `public_html` folder—to make sure the server is even responding properly!